# How can I deal with image file with django-pipeline?

Tags: django, django-pipeline

I use `django-pipeline` to deal with `css`, `javascript` files in my `Django` projects.

But I wonder how I could deal with `image` files using `django-pipeline`.

There is no manual for `image` in docs.

Should I use `Django` built-in `{% load staticfiles%}` for images?

Then should I use both `{% load staticfiles%}` and `{% load pipelines %}`?

Thanks.